# Adding Silverlight MimeType using adsutil

Tags: silverlight, iis-6, mime-types, xap

I have a script that creates an app pool, web site - and then I want to use adsutil to add the .xap MimeType.

I see this:

*cscript adsutil.vbs set W3SVC//Root/MimeMap “.extension,mimetype”*

However, since I am creating the web site in the same script I will not know the ID.

Would anyone know how to do this with adsutil?

Thanks,

- Rich

Comment: Can you show the part of the script that you use to create the website?

Answer (score -1):

You could always add the MimeType using web.config instead:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaml" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xap" mimeType="application/x-silverlight-app" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbap" mimeType="application/x-ms-xbap" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the rapid response!

I did try adding those lines to my web.config file.  However, when I tried redirecting to the site I received the same error:
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application
Code: 2104
Category: InitializeError
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application.  check web server settings